# How to detect desktop is locked in javascript

Tags: javascript

A simple question that I just can't find an answer for. I want to stop a periodic AJAX call when the user has wandered away and locked their PC. I don't need it to be every OS compatible or every browser (Chrome and IE would be good).

setInterval just doesn't seem to stop when locked and AJAX is also not prevented. The visibilitychange event seems to think that the tab is visible unless you switch to another tab.

I have stated javascript, but I only care that it can be done within the browser without asking the user.

Edge does seem to indicate it is hidden when locked, so I'm ok with that browser.

Thanks

Comment: In your javascript it is not possible to detect if the OS UI has locked. You would need to write a browser plugin to do this.

Comment: Rats, I was just trying to edit my post to say that I didn't want to use chrome.idle in an extension  but you beat me to it! Thanks anyway

Comment: @bhspencer I suggest posting that as an answer

Comment: @gladsocc I'm inclined to agree with you

Comment: You can detect when the window has lost focus, which is close enough to idle.

Comment: Yep, I detect that, but users quite often drag the tab onto a second screen and carry on working. I do want to refresh the data then, just not when they can't see it at all (i.e. when they click on another tab - which I have covered or when they lock their PC)

Comment: If it were me I would detect any input user within the web app and if there was not interaction from the user for 30mins popup a netflix style "Are you still watching" dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript it is not possible to detect if the OS UI has locked. The browser sand box prevents this kind of access to OS resources for security reasons. You would need to write a browser plugin to do this.

Comment: Whilst this answer isn't helpful in the sense it allowed me to fix the problem, I think it does release me to consider other options and it does confirm my own findings. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Idle.js](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Idle.js) library to detect if the user is looking away from the browser window or is inactive (his input devices are inactive).

Whatever the case, there's not a reliable way to get the OS or the screen saver state from the browser

Comment: I've just tried the demo, it reports 'away' when locked or when the tab is undocked but visible on another monitor, which is near enough the same behaviour as I have observed using setInterval, visibilitychange event and focus. Good idea though.