# Handle web app Javascript notifications better when screen is locked

Tags: javascript, web

In my web app I create desktop notifications on some page loads, depending on the state of things, and the page loads every two minutes.  It's a simple notification, like this:

```
// if warning applies:
new Notification("Warning!", {body: "You must take some action"});
```

meaning that if you have the app open (and the warning applies) then you'll get a pop up every couple of minutes but each will disappear after about 20 seconds (whatever the browser behavior is).

So far, so good.  My problem is what happens when the user's PC is locked.  If the user comes back to their locked PC after a period where notifications should have popped up, then they will find they all try to pop up in series, meaning they have to either wait a long time for them to clear or close them all -- annoying!

The behavior I would really like is that the notifications should go through their normal lifecycle while the screen is locked, i.e. popup and disappear.  Failing that, I would like them to simply not fire if the screen is locked.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I feel this is more like a question for http://ux.stackexchange.com/ because it sounds like there must be a better way to achieve whatever goal you're missing with these notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to detect desktop is locked in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928680/how-to-detect-desktop-is-locked-in-javascript) and [Can JavaScript detect when the PC is locked or the screensaver activates?](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24543142/Can-JavaScript-detect-when-the-PC-is-locked-or-the-screensaver-activates.html) for discussion about detection idle state.

In short: you can't check if screen is locked on web, but you can in browser extension.

---

For notifications you can [close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/close) any previous notifications before showing new:

```
function spawnNotification(theBody, theIcon, theTitle, prevNotification) {
  var options = {
      body: theBody,
      icon: theIcon
  }

  // Close previous notification before showing new one
  prevNotification.close.call(prevNotification)

  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
  setTimeout(n.close.bind(n), 4000);

  return n
}
```

Comment: Yeah, if you follow the first link the answer about Idle.js is good. If you don't want to use the code you can try to write something yourself to check to see if the user is moving the mouse or interacting with the page itself

Comment: @clurect, not really good for notifications. While using notifications API you assume that user is on the other page and you need to push your back to your page to perform some action. [Idle.js](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Idle.js) is about checking whether user interacting with your page or not. It can't know about interacting with a browser or a system.